# Xampp server conflict due to which wamp server is not working

Tags: xampp, wamp, conflict

I installed Xampp on my pc it was working fine but today all of a sudden apache server failed to initialize then i removed it and installed Wampserver which is perfectly working and services are online. But whenever i try to open localhost it is not working and browser still displaying Xampp fevicon and displays message "http:/localhost/ is not available" Any help would be appreciated thanks

Comment: Do you try with the ip:  paste this ip to your browser 127.0.0.1

Comment: This is a caching issue inside your browser. Clear its cache. Then reload.

Comment: Tried ip but not working Mohit.
I cleared all the history caches and everything but it is still not working just fevicon has gone away @arkascha

Comment: So you serve "services" from a local WAMP installation? And address them how?

Comment: Wamp is being successfully installed and its all services are also started. The icon is orange. But whenever I click on  localhost chrome opens a tab but it shows a message "This webpage is not available. Skype is not running. I am so confused what to do or what not to ? @arkascha

Comment: Ah, sorry, miss understood that term "services". What does "skype" have to do with an http server installation? First check if the local http server runs and is reachable. Use the telnet utility for this. On a command line connect to the localhost http server like that: `telnet localhost 80`. What happens?

Comment: delete xamp registry in system than open

Comment: Skype uses the same port which wampserver also uses I.e  it cause problems.  My problem still persists @arkascha

Comment: Skype itself is a single problem. One should not use it. Its main purpose is sniffing.

Comment: Thanks all.

Actually, MS visual C++ Redistributeable 2012 is needed for wampserver. I installed MS visual alongside Wampserver while it was giving error so wamp was not installed correctly. After re-installing the wamp server. It is working fine. Special thanks to you for helping @arkascha

Comment: I didn't understand much from this, but fine you sorted things out! Have a great sunday!

Answer (score 0):

Following steps worked for me:

1. start services of xampp from xampp control panel, and then go to the browser.
2. in the address bar,type: 127.0.0.1/8080/filename.php where filename.php is the php file placed in xampp/htdocs and you will have to change the port 80 to 8080 by configuring apache Config option from xampp control panel.

Answer (score 0):

Fixx....
see in your pc IIS services also running.. when IIS services running wamp server or xampp running only partially.. specially apache service not running on your pc.
do solutions...

1. for stop IIS on your system .. Go startmenu--type cmd--run-- type command
   **iisreset /stop**
   and enter.
2. now restart wamp server or xampp.. all services starts now. enjoy